# Delay of data of inputs and textarea after sorting

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I have a div with input fields which I used the sortableJS for sorting in my application. After sorting, they is a delay when you input any data for input fields. I don't understand what is happening, can anyone help me on this.

I used the following plugin for sorting

https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/

I used the code as follows:

```
var el = document.getElementById('items');
var startIndex;
Sortable.create(el, {
    handle: '.move',
    ghostClass: 'ghost',
    onStart: function (evt, dataTransfer) {
        startIndex = evt.oldIndex;
    },
    onUpdate: function (evt) {
        //swap the data.
    }
});
```

Comment: A small JSBin demonstrating the issue would be tremendously helpful

Comment: I am able to fix the issue. I changed the statement from import Sortable from 'sortablejs/modular/sortable.complete.esm.js' to import Sortable from 'sortablejs/modular/sortable.core.esm.js. It started working